# Reducing boilerplate with associations

Tags: associations, meta-programming

I'm looking for advice either on alternative ways to approach my problem in general, or specifically on meta-programming (which seems to me to be a way around this). In my work I have databases of geometrical objects (points and vectors) that are stored with a field per component ("foo_x, foo_y, foo_z"). I've adopted a style of working with these where I use DatabaseLink to query the DB and get all of my fields, then I create a new association with real Mathematica lists so that I can work with them more naturally for the rest of the notebook. Here's an example with obviously a dummy data source.

```
rawData = <|"FooX" -> #[[1]], "FooY" -> #[[2]], "FooZ" -> #[[3]], "BarX" -> #[[4]], "BarY" -> #[[5]], "BarZ" -> #[[6]]|> & /@ 
RandomReal[{1, 10}, {10, 6}]
vectorData = <|"Foo" -> {#FooX, #FooY, #FooZ}, "Bar" -> {#BarX, #BarY, #BarZ}|> & /@ rawData
ListPointPlot3D[vectorData[[All, "Foo"]]]
```

(The ListPlot is just to illustrate why I bother with vectorData). The code in vectorData is the boilerplate I want to reduce though. I've already listed the fields in the query to populate rawData and the fields have a consistent naming scheme. The rule really is as simple as `<|"___"-> {#___X, #___Y, #___Z}|>` so I'm hoping there is a way I can generate vectorData generically without having to always duplicate field names between the DB query and the "nice" representation. Does anyone know a way to accomplish that (or, stepping back, have a better approach to this kind of workflow?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
vectorize[label_, assocs_] := Map[
  label -> Lookup[#, {label <> "X", label <> "Y", label <> "Z"}] &,
  assocs
  ]

Association /@ Transpose[vectorize[#, rawData] & /@ {"Foo", "Bar"}]
```

Perhaps you don't need the intermediate format `rawData` or the association `vectorData`. You could just query the database directly like:

```
vectors[label_, conn_] := SQLSelect[conn, "table", {label <> "_x", label <> "_y", label <> "_z"}]
```

Although I haven't tried it, I think this should give you the matrix you are looking for.

At the top of your file, you might put a list of variables like this:

```
foo = vectors["Foo", conn];
bar = vectors["Bar", conn];
```

Or you could also put them in an `Association`, as you wish. If you really want associations in your format (which is not necessarily the way to go) then you could use `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[<| "Foo" -> #, "Bar" -> #2 |>, {foo, bar}]
```

The reason it might not be the way to go is that it might be preferable to use `MapThread` directly when doing computations, rather than working with `Association`s.

Comment: Great solution! In the first code box, I assume that the call should be "vectorize", right?

Comment: @FredrikD Correct, updated. Thanks.